# Passing BIT in query as a parameter in Prepared Statement

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I want to pass a bit as one of the parameters in Prepared Statement. My query should look like this :

```
query = select * from tbl_security_details('user',O::BIT)
```

I am framing the query as :

```
query = select * from tbl_security_details(?,?)
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1,"user")
ps.setString(2,"0::BIT")
```

However, this throws an error.

Can someone explain how I can pass 0::BIT from the prepare statement without it appending the single quote by itself and getting converted to String ?

Comment: Why don't you use a `boolean`?

Comment: tried ps.setboolean(2,false). Didn't work

Comment: "Didn't work" is neither a valid Java error nor a valid Postgres error message (using a boolean obviously also requires to use a proper boolean in the database, not misuse a bit for a boolean flag)

Comment: Have you tried using `setInt(2, 0)`?

Comment: Yes. Both setInt(2,0) and setBoolean(2,false) resulted in Postgres error

Answer (score 1):

Write the prepared statement so that the cast is part of the query:

```
String query = "select * from tbl_security_details(?, ?::bit)";
java.sql.PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, "user");
ps.setString(2, "0");
```

That is necessary, because you can only pass a constant value to the prepared statement, not an SQL expression.